# How to show that there is a non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $A \in O(n)$ s.t $Av=\pm v$ whenever $n$ is odd.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

Intuitively, this makes sense, but just in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, when any $A$ is given, this $A$ determines how much should a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be rotated about the origin for each axis. So, if we think of such rotation as a circular movement (which is always happening on some plane,) we can find some normal vector of a circle (plane). And, as $A$ doesn't move any nonzero point on an axis given by the normal vector, we can see that any nonzero point on the $\pm$normal vector will satisfy $Av=\pm v$.

However, I am having trouble showing why this works for every odd $n$. Also, I wonder how I should use my approach to write a mathematical proof.

Maybe I should bring the concept of the linear hyperplane $H$ to use my approach. As $A$ gives us an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I guess we could eliminate one of the elements in the basis to create $H$, which is a similar process that I used.

Moreover, I wonder we can say this is true only when $n$ is odd because we get a counterexample when $n=2$, right?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what are the possible complex eigenvalues of $A$? How many of them can be non-real, given that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has real coefficients and $n$ is odd?

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you! But, is there something more geometrical proof? I wish I could show any orthogonal transformation can be decomposed into reflections on some hyperplane.

Comment: It's definitely not true that any orthogonal transformation can be decomposed into reflections on a single hyperplane; and I don't immediately see how a decomposition into more general reflections implies the desired statement.

Comment: Your edited answer doesn't seem correct to me. It doesn't make sense to define the factors $R$ on individual planes—every linear transformation has to be defined on the entire space.

Comment: @GregMartin You're right, showing for eigenvalue was the easiest one! Thanks a lot!

Comment: for $n$ odd, you can assume WLOG that $A \in SO(n)$ and then decompose $A$ into at most $n-1$ reflections (Householder matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intuitively, this makes sense, but just in R^3.

Heh. Does it, though? How would you describe what all the elements of $O(3)$ are? The result is obvious given that description, but you have to do at least a little work to get the description.

Anyway, you can show the result with algebra. The characteristic polynomial has odd degree, so it has a real root $\lambda$, in which case $A-\lambda I$ has nontrivial kernel in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is an eigenvector $v$ with $Av=\lambda v$. Since $A$ is an isometry, you can take the norm of both sides to get $|\lambda|=1~\Rightarrow~\lambda=\pm1$.

More generally, you can massage the spectral theorem to tell you every $A\in O(V)$ (where $V$ is an inner product space) is, in some basis, equivalent to a block-diagonal matrix, where the blocks are $2\times2$ rotation matrices with possibly one $1\times1$ block $[\pm1]$ in the corner (depending on $\det A=\pm1$).